# ValueOutofRange error

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-import

I am trying to upload some records in a DAta Extension and getting the ValueOutOfRange error. Apparently, all field data types and lengths are correct. Could you please advise the reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just got this error, and it looks like my DATE field is the issue - some of my dates are listed as 12/31/0069 - so the year appears to be the cause of the failure.

I realize this post is over 2 years old now, but in case others have this issue they can try looking at the Date Time values first.